# How to check list of selected images BindableLayout in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to upload images in Xamarin to Server via API.

.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="pickimg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Margin="0">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource Color="#ddd" Size="22" FontFamily="MaterIcon" Glyph="{x:Static local:FontIconsClass.Camera}"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="pickimg_Tapped" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>

<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout x:Name="listImg" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True" CornerRadius="4">
                    <Image HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="70" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding .}"/>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

.xaml.cs

This is how I display the list of selected photos:

```
async void pickimg_Tapped(System.Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pickResult = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(5, MediaFileType.Image);
    if(pickResult?.Files == null)
    {
        return;
    }    
    else
    {
        var imgList = new List<ImageSource>();
        foreach (var img in pickResult?.Files)
        {
            var stream = await img.OpenReadAsync();
            imgList.Add(ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream));
        }
        BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(listImg, imgList);
    }    
}
```

Everything seems fine. And I have 1 button to post the image to the Server:

```
private async void bt_addfeed_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getResult = listImg;//How can I check and get the list of images in listImg? 

    if(getResult == null)
    {
        return;
    }    
    else
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StreamContent(await getResult.OpenReadAsync()), "file", getResult.FileName);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);......
    }    

}
```

How can I check and get the list of images in `listImg`? Please solutions, Thanks

**Update...**

```
List<ImageSource> imgList = new List<ImageSource>();
async void pickimg_Tapped(System.Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pickResult = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(5, MediaFileType.Image);
        if(pickResult?.Files == null)
        {
            return;
        }    
        else
        {
            
            foreach (var img in pickResult?.Files)
            {
                var stream = await img.OpenReadAsync();
                imgList.Add(ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream));
            }
            BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(listImg, imgList);
        }    
    }

private async void bt_addfeed_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var getResult = imgList;
    
        if(getResult == null)
        {
            return;
        }    
        else
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new StreamContent(await getResult.OpenReadAsync()), "file", getResult.FileName);
    
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("", content);......
        }    
    
    }
```

How can `getResult` get `.FileName` and `.OpenReadAsync()`?

`content.Add(new StreamContent(await getResult.OpenReadAsync()), "file", getResult.FileName);`

Comment: Do you want to get the clicked picture information?

Comment: Oh no, I just want to save that image through the API to the Server

Comment: According to your updated code, your getResult is of type List<ImageSource>. It is a list, if you want to manipulate a piece of information, it is best to use a loop. Get an ImageSource through the loop, and then use the **.FileName** to get it.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring `imgList` as a local variable, so it only has scope inside the method where you declare it

```
var imgList = new List<ImageSource>();
```

instead, declare it as a class level variable so it will be accessible throughout the page

```
// do this inside the class body, but NOT within a specific method
List<ImageSource> imgList = new List<ImageSource>();
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can `getResult` get the `.FileName` ? I tried `content.Add(new StreamContent(await getResult.OpenReadAsync()), "file", getResult.FileName);` but it doesn't seem to be ok