# Get a list of images of BindableLayout in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045124/how-to-check-list-of-selected-images-bindablelayout-in-xamarin), however the problem is not solved perfectly. I posted another question for more clarity.

I'm trying to upload an image through the API. As in the code below, I have an image selector button, the list shows the selected images. And 1 button to post the image.

I have a list of pictures:

```
<Grid x:Name="pickimg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Margin="0">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource Color="#ddd" Size="22" FontFamily="MaterIcon" Glyph="{x:Static local:FontIconsClass.Camera}"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="pickimg_Tapped" />
    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
</Grid>

<StackLayout x:Name="listImg" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" Padding="0" IsClippedToBounds="True" CornerRadius="4">
                <Image HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="70" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding .}"/>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
<Button x:Name="bt_addfeed" Clicked="bt_addfeed_Clicked" CornerRadius="7" FontSize="13" Text="Post" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
```

.xaml.cs

```
List<ImageSource> imgList = new List<ImageSource>();

async void pickimg_Tapped(System.Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pickResult = await MediaGallery.PickAsync(5, MediaFileType.Image);
    if(pickResult?.Files == null)
    {
        return;
    }    
    else
    {
        //var imgList = new List<ImageSource>();
        foreach (var img in pickResult?.Files)
        {
            var stream = await img.OpenReadAsync();
            imgList.Add(ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream));
        }
        BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(listImg, imgList);
    }    
}

private async void bt_addfeed_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var getResult = imgList;
    if (getResult == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var img in getResult)
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new StreamContent(await img.OpenReadAsync()), "file", img.FileName);
        
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var responses = await httpClient.PostAsync("xxxx/api/UploadFileFeeds", content);
        }
    }
}
```

How `img.FileName`? and `img.OpenReadAsync()`?

Please help, thanks

Comment: `getResult` is a `List<ImageSource>` that contains **multiple** objects.  Do you want to upload **each** object?  If so, then you need to use a `loop`

Comment: Sorry, my update was wrong. I have edited the above. How can save images for it?

Comment: [ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource?view=xamarin-forms) does not have methods `OpenReadAsync` or a `FileName` property

Comment: you probably want a `List<FileResult>`, not a `List<ImageSource>`

Comment: Well, if I change to `FileResult`, then `imgList.Add(FileResult.FromStream(() => stream));` --> `FromStream` not working?

Comment: you will either need to refactor your code to adjust to this change, or maintain two lists of objects, one using `FileResult` and one using `ImageSource`

Comment: Yes, this is my concern. I'm pretty stupid. Can you be more specific with your code? I've been thinking about converting a list of ImageSource to FileResult, but it doesn't seem right. Help from you. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

create two lists

```
List<ImageSource> imgList = new List<ImageSource>();
List<FileResult> fileList = new List<FileResult>();
```

then populate both of them

```
foreach (var img in pickResult?.Files)
{
   fileList.Add(img);
   var stream = await img.OpenReadAsync();
   imgList.Add(ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream));
}
BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(listImg, imgList);
```

then when you need to transfer the files, use `fileList`

```
foreach(var img in fileList)
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.Add(new StreamContent(await img.OpenReadAsync()), "file", img.FileName);
    
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var responses = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://v1api.venuskorea.com.vn/api/UploadFileFeeds", content);
    }
```

Comment: I get the error: `Cannot convert from 'NativeMedia.IMediaFile' to 'Xamarin.Essentials.FileResult`. At: `fileList.Add(img);`

Comment: then use `IMediaFile` instead of `FileResult`

Comment: Did you mean: `List<IMediaFile> fileList = new List<IMediaFile>();`?? This makes `img.FileName` not working :(

Comment: https://github.com/FelipeNicoletto/MediaFilesManager/blob/master/MediaFilesManager.Abstractions/Interfaces/IMediaFile.cs

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I'm using MediaGallery Plugin, so it gives error: cannot convert from 'NativeMedia.IMediaFile' to '...IMediaFile'

Comment: then look at the `IMediaFile` declaration for that plugin